# Ho do you uninstall another app on Wix bootstrapper uninstall?

Tags: wix, uninstallation, bootstrapper

I have a bootstrapper installer. This bootstrapper includes 4 msi installer which are:

app1 v1.0
app2 v1.0
app3 v1.0
app4 v1.0

Bootstrapper installs and uninstalls all 4 apps as it should. No problems here. The problem starts when a user upgrades one of the 4. In this case the bootstrapper can not uninstall the app that the user upgraded.

Bundle.xws of the bootstrapper is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
  <Bundle Name="My Company apps" Version="1.0.1.0" Manufacturer="my Company" UpgradeCode="bootstrapper_upgradecode">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseUrl="" ShowVersion="yes" SuppressOptionsUI="yes" LogoFile="ATU_setup_64.png" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="D:\app1.1.0.1.0.msi" Visible="yes" />
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="D:\app2.1.0.1.0.msi" Visible="yes" />
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="D:\app3.1.0.1.0.msi" Visible="yes" />
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="D:\app4.1.0.1.0.msi" Visible="yes" />
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Question is how can I make the bootstrapper uninstaller to uninstall externally upgraded versions too?

Comment: Maybe uninstall by guid?

Comment: Edit: OK, when I use unique ProductCode on the app msi the product guid never changes so the bootstrapper can uninstall even if the app is upgraded. However using unique ProductCode disallow the app to be upgraded. This is very strange. Why can I not have unique ProductCode and UpgradeCode at the same time?